# ListView: Change ContextMenu Header According To Column Value (Style Trigger?)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

Good Evening Everyone,

I am trying to change a WPF ListView ContextMenu header depending on a column value from said ListView. Specifically I want to change it from Enable to Disable (and vice-versa) when a column binded to the value of STATUS = "Y"(hold) or "N"(not on hold). I have tried the following:

```
 <ContextMenu.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding STATUS}" Value="Y">
                 <Setter Property="Header" Value="Enable" />
             </DataTrigger>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding STATUS}" Value="N">
                 <Setter Property="Header" Value="Disable" />
             </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
 </ContextMenu.Resources>
```

2ND Attempt:

```
 <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="cmlv">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="cmdisableenable">
                        <MenuItem.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding STATUS}" Value="Y">
                                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="Enable" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding STATUS}" Value="N">
                                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="Disable" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </MenuItem.Resources>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           <MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding STATUS}" Value="Y">
                                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="Enable" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding STATUS}" Value="N">
                                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="Disable" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>

                    </MenuItem.Resources>
                </MenuItem>
```

You have apply style on MenuItem so depends  on status the header will be Disable or Enable and make sure u dont assign any value to header

Comment: I tried that out (2nd attempt), and I tried with lvoperators.STATUS for my binding as well (it ran, but I still don't get my header set). Any other ideas I can try (I would think this is close)?

Comment: @DevelopingDEV its working for me ok i attached the prjt also take a look add wts missing i try to help (prjt)[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZIbLcVF8a2A2s0HffpnnR7BsPGE4njS0/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: I did get this working, but the property was being applied across all the listview items (which is what your example also illustrated). What I discovered that the Opened event was working for me, however when I first tried it I had the multiselect active, and that was holding back my desired effect. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DevelopingDEV any time